Getting a domain/app's categories by quering the chrome://topics-internals/ Classifier directly
Chrome's Topics API's internal tool chrome://topics-internals/ has a Classifier that can list which categories a domain/app belongs to, as determined by an offline file (which is shipped with Chrome) called model.tflite. All queries are done strictly via various offline Chrome JavaScript files without using any connections.
But since the interface is rather basic (no option to download/export the results, no sorting, etc.) is there a way to program a webpage (with standard webpage programming like HTML5, JS, PHP, etc.) to either interact with it via API or just query the tflite file directly?
P.S.
I did develop a JavaScript code that adds a download button and converts the list to CSV, but the chrome:// protocol prevents bookmarklets, so the only way to run it is to throw the JS code into Chrome DevTools' Console, which is good for me but not to share with end users.

With my JS:

